# JavaFX Scene builder - more objects without Scene builder

Tags: javafx

I created a GUI in Scenebuilder. 2 rectangles. A circle should be displayed for a KeyEvent. The circle is not displayed (playShoot()). Can objects be inserted without Scenebuilder? I think yes, but how?  Do you have an idea?

Controller Class

```
public class PlayAnonymController{

    @FXML
    private Rectangle PLAYER;
    
    @FXML
    private Label gamoverLabel;

    @FXML
    private Label scoreLabel;
    
  //Variablen
    public enum Direction {
        LEFT, RIGHT, SPACE, NONE
    }
    
    double cX;
    
    public static List<Circle> bullets = new ArrayList<>();
    
    
    @FXML
    public void movePlayer(KeyEvent event) throws IOException{      
        KeyCode key = event.getCode();  // keyboard code for the pressed key
//        System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + key);  // for testing
            switch (event.getCode()) {
            case LEFT:
                moveLeft();
              break;
            case RIGHT:
                moveRight();
               break;         
            case SPACE:
                playerShoot();
                break;
            }
    }
    
    
    public void playerShoot() {

    System.out.println("Test");
    Circle circle = new Circle(50, 50, 50);
    circle.setFill(Color.RED);
    }

    void moveLeft() {
        PLAYER.setTranslateX(cX-=10);
    }

    void moveRight() {
        PLAYER.setTranslateX(cX+=10);
    }
}
```

My FXML file from Scenebuilder. At the bottom of   the circle should be visible after a KeyEvent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>


<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.PlayAnonymController">
   <top>
      <BorderPane prefHeight="37.0" prefWidth="600.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <left>
            <Label fx:id="scoreLabel" text="Label" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
         </left>
         <center>
            <Label fx:id="gamoverLabel" text="Label" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
         </center>
      </BorderPane>
   </top>
   <bottom>
      <Label text="Move: Pfeiltaste links / recht. Schießen Space." BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </bottom>
   <center>
      <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Rectangle fx:id="PLAYER" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#000911" height="5.0" layoutX="280.0" layoutY="305.0" onKeyPressed="#movePlayer" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="40.0" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: Yes, of course. Simply add the `Circle` to the desired layout (e.g., `someLayout.getChildren().add(theCircle)`). To get access to the layout just inject it into the controller like you're doing for the two labels and the rectangle. Note that FXML is not as special/magical as it may seem. You're simply defining an object graph in XML format, but under the hood "all it's doing" is calling the same constructors and methods that you can call in code yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Inject with @FXML private Circle circle? Do I need to add a start() method in the controller and include someLayout.getChildren().add(theCircle))?

Comment: Not Circle.  Whatever you have as your top level (root) container in your FXML.  It'll probably be an AnchorPane because SceneBuilder users always love AnchorPane.  So you @FXML AnchorPane someLayout (whatever you've called that root element).  Then the someLayout.getChildren().add(theCircle)

Comment: And there's no reason to add a `start()` method (if you mean the method from `Application`, then note an FXML controller should never extend from `Application`). You're creating the `Circle` in the `playerShoot()` method. Just add it to the injected layout in that method. Note a "layout" is typically something like an `AnchorPane`, `BorderPane`, `StackPane`, `Pane`, `VBox`, `HBox`, or similar. A `Circle` is not a layout.

Comment: That's my problem. How can I access the <center><Pane><children> layout in the FXML? I do not understand that. A circle should later appear in the layout pane.

Comment: The Pane has no ID. I've adjusted that now. It works out. :-) Thanks @Slaw